# Difference between proving $\forall n(Q(n) \implies P(n))$ and $\forall nQ(n) \implies \forall nP(n)$

Tags: logic, proof-verification

From what I can understand an almost identical proof structure is often used in a direct proof. To prove $\forall n(Q(n) \implies P(n))$ the common would be:
(1.) Let $n$ be arbitrary.
(2.) Assume $Q(n)$
(3.) Prove $P(n)$
(4.) Conclude that since $n$ is arbitrary, $\forall n(Q(n) \implies P(n))$

On the other hand, to prove $\forall nQ(n) \implies \forall nP(n)$ only a minor tweak is needed:
(1.) Assume $\forall n Q(n)$
(2.) Let $n$ be arbitrary, so that you can use $Q(n)$
(3.) Prove $P(n)$
(4.) Conclude that since $n$ is arbitrary, $\forall nQ(n) \implies \forall nP(n))$

This suggests to me that whenever I can prove one of the statements I can also prove the other one, because the only change I will need to do is to change the two first steps in the proof which of course always is possible.I feel like this implies equivalence, but the statments are not equivalent, so I do not understand how this can be true? Am I doing something wrong in the proof outline or is it something else I have missed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've presented a way of proving $\forall nQ(n) \implies \forall nP(n)$ that only works if in fact $\forall n(Q(n) \implies P(n))$ also holds. In the example from user 1's proof, you can't use this approach to prove $\forall nQ(n) \implies \forall nP(n)$, even though it's true, because you'd need to conclude $n\gt10$ from $n\gt1$. So you're right that if you can use one of these proofs you can also use the other, but you're wrong in assuming that being able to use these particular proofs is equivalent to being able to prove these two statements.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I'm following this entirely. I actually came to the conclusion after looking at user1's example that the two first steps are not unimportant as I first thought, since the fact that $\forall n Q(n)$ can be used in the proof of $P(n)$ makes the third step of the second proof outline possibly different from the third step in the first proof outline. In the second I have both $\forall n Q(n)$ and $Q(n)$ to work with, so I should be able to use the fact that for example $Q(n-1)$, which I can not do in the first proof outline.

Comment: @hampadampadoo: Well, looking at it that way, yes, then you can prove it in the second outline; but then the second line of that outline doesn't make sense. I interpreted it to mean that you want to prove $P(n)$ in 3. specifically for the $n$ introduced in step 2, using $Q(n)$. If you're going to use all of 1. anyway, there's no reason to restrict it to a particular arbitrary $n$ first. For instance, if $P(n)=Q(5)$, then $Q(n)$ from 2. is irrelevant, you need $Q(5)$ from 1.

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood the use of letting $n$ be arbitrary. In the second step of the second outline, what we actually end up with after letting $n$ be arbitrary is $\forall n Q(n) \implies P(n)$. That is, the arbitrary $n$ refers to the consequent rather than the antecedent. Maybe it would be appropriate to use different letters. And then of course $n$ can be plugged in to $\forall n Q(n)$ If we would want to, just as any other number. I feel like you understand what my problem is better than myself, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

These are different:
Let $Q(n)$ be $n\gt 1$, and $P(n)$ be $n\gt 10$.
$\forall n(Q(n) \implies P(n))$ is not true ; take $n=2$.
$\forall nQ(n) \implies \forall nP(n)$ is true; since $\forall nQ(n)$ is false.

---

> $\forall n(Q(n) \implies P(n))$ implies $\forall nQ(n) \implies \forall nP(n)$. Can you see this?

Comment: I can see the implication. I appreciate your example, even if it was not pinpointing exactly what was wrong in my reasoning. I see now that the two first steps are actually not trivial for the rest of the proof. Thanks!